# Problem when using react link or redirect

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a routing problem, I will demonstrate how I'm doing:

I have a routes.js

```
    return (
        <BrowserRouter> 
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" exact component={Login}/>
                <Route path="/inicio" component={Inicio}/>
                <Route path="/servico" component={Servico}/>
                <Route path="/colaborador" component={Colaborador}/>
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}
```

App.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <Container>
        <NavLeft />
        <Screen>
            <Routes />
        </Screen>
      </Container>
      <GlobalStyle />
    </>
  );
}
```

My Routes is the routes.js file and inside my NavLeft, I have all my navigation structure

When I add a link, in this navigation, the following error message is returned to me
×

> Error: Invariant failed: You should not use  outside a

since Link doesn't work, I thought of creating a function to redirect

```
clickRedirect = route =>{  
    return <Redirect to={route} />
 }
```

The redirect does not give an error, but it does nothing

What can I do to make my Link work or my Redirect?

i am using the `"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0"`,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `NavLeft` component is not contained within the Router, so it cannot Link or push to any routes within it. The Router should usually live at the top of the component tree - it will not have an effect on the other components. Consider this structure instead:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Header />
      <Container>
        <NavLeft />
        <Screen>
            <Routes />
        </Screen>
      </Container>
      <GlobalStyle />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

```
function Routes() {
  return ( 
      <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Login}/>
          <Route path="/inicio" component={Inicio}/>
          <Route path="/servico" component={Servico}/>
          <Route path="/colaborador" component={Colaborador}/>
      </Switch>
    )
}
}
```

Comment: Okay, thank you, I followed the structure you said and it worked, thank you very much